# Patch class imported inside function in Python

Tags: python, mocking

I have:

folder/cats.py

```
class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def meow():
        pass
```

folder/something.py

```
def something():
    from folder.cats import Cat

    scootish_fold = Cat(color='Black')
    scootish_fold.meow()
```

How do I patch `meow()`?

I tried:

```
@patch('folder.something.Cat.meow')
def test_meow(self, cat_meow_patch):
    cat_patch.return_value = 'MEOWW!'
```

But I keep getting an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always patch the module/class with its original package/module path:

```
@patch('folder.cats.Cat.meow')
def test_meow(self, cat_meow_patch):
    cat_patch.return_value = 'MEOWW!'
```